# 0pt=0mm 0pt=0mm before and after figure

Tags: floats, longtable

When I put a figure to Latex doc I got "0pt=0mm 0pt=0mm" before and after the figure. Below is the environment which I used. The itneresting thing is that when I put this into very basic doc then everything is OK but when I paste my code to very advanced doc with many packages etc then this problem occured. What may be the reason?

```
% Long figure
\newenvironment{longfigure}[2][]{%
  % #1 (optional) is arbitrary code to be executed before the longtable
  % #2 is the column specification
  \renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}%
  \expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{figure}%
  \setcounter{subfigure}{0}%
  \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\LTright}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}
  
  #1%
  \begin{longtable}{#2}
}{\end{longtable}}
```

Comment: Please post a small but complete test file. But shouldn't `\alphalph{\value{subfigure}` not have `\value`?

Comment: what longtable column spec do you use? setting LTleft and right both to 0pt means you have to be very careful with the column specification

Comment: if this fragemnt causes no issues in a small document, the problem is in code you have not shown